# Separating header from body following curl call in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am making a curl call (using PHP), to a REST API, and I am requesting both the headers and body, using the following curl options:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE, 
CURLOPT_NOBODY => FALSE
```

The call is a success, and I'm getting the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 18:42:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 65
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1000
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 997
X-Rate-Reset: 81505
ETag: W/"41-ltrGtAoAWpkb+p1Y+yju9w"

{"name":"jim","gender":"male","probability":0.99,"count":1805}
```

I am interested in:

```
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 997
```

and the JSON:

```
{"name":"jim","gender":"male","probability":0.99,"count":1805}
```

This has to work on Windows systems and linux systems. I tried saving the output to $string, and then using:

```
explode ("\r\n", $string);
```

and

```
explode ("\n", $string);
```

But, it's not working. I could get the headers, and op result separately, but that's 2 API calls, and I am rate limited.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
curl_close($ch);

$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

$headers = explode("\n", $header);
```

Comment: Isn't substr($response, 0, $header_size) the same as substr($response,  $header_size)

Comment: No, is not this same. substr($response, 0, $header_size) returns from 0 to position which is number of chars in header. substr($response, $header_size) returns from char after header  to the end of a string

Comment: Yes, this works. Although, I went about it differently. I already have the header_size in the info portion of my data structyre